# Change position of individual tick label

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, ticks

Using a `ycomb` plot which goes below 0 means one of my tick labels is obscured by the line. How do I move this individual tick to above the x axis? Is there a way to do it without having to use the `extra x ticks` options?

Also, how could I remove the nodes near coords that have a value of 0?

Thanks

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        tick style={draw=none},
        yticklabels=none,
        axis x line=middle,
        axis y line=middle,
        xmin=-2,
        xmax=4.5,
        xlabel=$n$,
        ymin=-0.5,
        ymax=2.5,
        ylabel={$x[n]$},
        nodes near coords,
        nodes near coords align={south east}
        ]
        \addplot+[ycomb,thick,mark=o] plot coordinates
            {(-2,0) (-1,-0.5) (0,1) (1,2) (2,0) (3,1) (4,0)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Adding `axis on top=true` to the `axis` options would put the axis on the top, therefore the tick would not be hidden, but the plot at x==0 would then be hidden by the y axis.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If its only one tick label, you could use

```
x tick label style={yshift={(\ticknum==2)*2em}}
```

or

```
x tick label style={yshift={(\tick==-1)*2em}}
```

And you can add the following to remove the `nodes near coords` with value `0`:

```
nodes near coords={%
  \pgfmathprintnumberto[assume math mode]{\pgfplotspointmeta}{\nodenearcoord}%
  \pgfmathparse{\nodenearcoord==0?:\nodenearcoord}%
  $\pgfmathresult$%
}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        tick style={draw=none},
        yticklabels=none,
        axis x line=middle,
        axis y line=middle,
        xmin=-2,
        xmax=4.5,
        xlabel=$n$,
        ymin=-0.5,
        ymax=2.5,
        ylabel={$x[n]$},
        nodes near coords={%
          \pgfmathprintnumberto[assume math mode]{\pgfplotspointmeta}{\nodenearcoord}%
          \pgfmathparse{\nodenearcoord==0?:\nodenearcoord}%
          $\pgfmathresult$%
        },
        nodes near coords align={south east},
        x tick label style={yshift={(\tick==-1)*2em}}
        ]
        \addplot+[ycomb,thick,mark=o] plot coordinates
            {(-2,0) (-1,-0.5) (0,1) (1,2) (2,0) (3,1) (4,0)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```